# UIImage not being displayed when retrived from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, core-data, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

Help please :)

I have set up a mutable array as follows

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TopImage"  inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];


NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"topImage" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];


NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResultsT = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResultsT == nil) {
}

[self setTopImageArray:mutableFetchResultsT];}
```

And im trying to populate a UIImageView using :

```
- (void)showPhoto:(NSInteger)numberToAdd
{

[topIV setImage:[topImageArray objectAtIndex:currentPI + numberToAdd]];

}
```

currentPI is an integer marking current image in index and number to add is set here:

```
- (IBAction)nextTouch
{
[self showPhoto:-1];

}
```

This will skip to next image (thankyou to @XenElement for this insight).

No images load in UIImageView at all.

MutableArray is getting populated through imagePickerController.

The following is my dedicated Image>Data Data>Image converter class

```
@implementation Image2Data

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
return YES;
}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
return [NSData class];
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
return UIImagePNGRepresentation(value);
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
return [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:value] autorelease];
}

@end
```

This is initialized in my managed objects class with:

```
+ (void)initialize {
if (self == [Images class]) {
    Image2Data *transformer = [[Image2Data alloc] init];
    [NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:transformer forName:@"Image2Data"];
}
 }
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

DetartrateD

I had originally put:

```
[topImageArray insertObject:imageS atIndex:0];
```

corrected to:

```
[topImageArray insertObject:imageS.topImage atIndex:0];
```

:)))) big laugh, I was pointing to my entity not its attribute ahh well, lesson learned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that you are storing the image as a `UIImage` object. You must be converting it into a `NSData` object before storing it. You must convert it back to a `UIImage` object using `initWithData:` prior to setting it to the `UIImageView` instance.

Comment: @Deepak thanks for your suggestion but i manage the transformation/reverse transformation in a dedicated class I have included a code snip above. As far as I know, I would not need to re-convert the image in my viewController class as It would be done already OR would the contents of the mutable array need to be converted back to UIImage ?

Comment: @Deepak no, checking mutable array: NSLog(@"%i" , [topImageArray count]);  right after adding image confirms array being fed. Stopping and rebuilding, running:  NSLog(@"%i" , [topImageArray count]); in viewDidLoad also confirms objects being correctly held (number of objects correct).....

Comment: I was referring to image objects. Can you check if the reverse transformation is working properly.

Comment: @Deepak, thank you so far by the way, could you suggest an NSLog script to run for finding this out and where to run it ? (im still pretty new to this game:)

Comment: Try `- (void)showPhoto:(NSInteger)numberToAdd
{
 UIImage *image = [topImageArray objectAtIndex:currentPI + numberToAdd];
 if ( image == nil ) {
  NSLog(@"nil image.");
 }
 [topIV setImage:image];
}` and see what turns up on the logs.

Comment: If images are not `nil`, are all the `IBOutlet`s connected? Specifically, is `topIV` connected to the `UIImageView` object in the NIB file?

Comment: ok, forget what I said, images are nil, I tweaked the code to get the NSLog script to work, so , what are your thoughts?

Comment: fixed! happy face:), credit to you for pointing me in the right direction. See above for detail's. Great tip you gave me on checking the returned value of the image objects, this was the key. Good luck and see you around...